# BotMan widget not replying, Using PHP Version 7.4.19 + Win 10 + XXAMP

Tags: php, botman

I am testing botman chat. Followed documentation at https://botman.io/2.0/installation

Script open the chat widget at right bottom corner, but when I enter hello, it does not reply. Have tried multiple forums but not getting any solution.

**Below is the script I am using**

Installed botman

```
composer require botman/botman
```

Web Deriver

```
composer require botman/driver-web
```

**index.php**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>COINS ChatBot</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
// Feel free to change the settings on your need
    var botmanWidget = {
        frameEndpoint: '/chat.html',
        chatServer: 'chat.php',
        title: 'ChatBot',
        introMessage: 'Hi and welcome to our chatbot how can i help you ?',
        placeholderText: 'Ask Me Something',
        mainColor: '#F28240',
        bubbleBackground: '#F28240',
        aboutText: '',
        aboutLink: '',
        bubbleAvatarUrl: 'https://www.applozic.com/assets/resources/images/Chat-Bot-Icon@512px.svg'
    };
        </script>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**chat.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BotMan Widget</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script id="botmanWidget" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

   use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
   use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
   use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;

   
   $config = [
    // Your driver-specific configuration
    // "telegram" => [
    //    "token" => "TOKEN"
    // ]
];

   DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class);

   $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

  // Give the bot something to listen for.
$botman->hears('hello', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
});

$botman->hears('Good Morning', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hey John');
});

$botman->hears('what is the time in {city} located in {continent}' , function (BotMan $bot,$city,$continent) {
     date_default_timezone_set("$continent/$city");
      $reply = "The time in ".$city." ".$continent." is ".date("h:i:sa");
    $bot->reply($reply);
});

$botman->fallback(function($bot) {
    $bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand these commands. Here is a list of commands I understand: ...');
});

// Start listening
$botman->listen();
?>
```

After checking I found may be issue with caching, I have installed APCU PHP Cache but still no luck.

Comment: Seems like step one would be using inspector's network panel to check requests and responses to/from chat.php.

Comment: And looking at your server's error logs.